# Which Database is Best for Magento

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, magento

Which database is best for more performance with Magento?

My Magento store using more than 80k products with 2k category.

My Question is :

```
1) Is Mysql database will enough to manage my product / category ranges ?
2) Or Shall i use any other database with Magento to keep the site loading fast ?
```

Any suggestion much appriciation.

Comment: Magento supports only mysql http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements that's why your question is meaningless...

Comment: This question is probably better suited for [MageOverflow](https://magento.stackexchange.com) as it is not a coding question but a question specific to the operation/administration of Magento.

Comment: I disagree with Zyava! There must be always a solution for any problem. I experimented the MSSQL with wordpress, offcourse I faced some coding difficulties and barriers but I am sure that we can make PHP to work with other DB also. MYSQL has size limitations. @ Man Kingdom, Magento is an advanced system and there must be some way to throttle the size of DB or we can use someother DB like Amazon Web services and bring the data indirectly from dynamodb to the website. Cheers to your research effort!!!

Comment: If you manage to hit size limitations with MySQL while running a magento site, then you'll have a whole heap of trouble with Magento itself long before any fictitious MySQL size issues become a problem

Comment: @BannedfromSO - `MYSQL has size limitations`.... please explain this sweeping comment.... what size issues are you talking about? or are you simply spreading FUD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also want to give Percona [Percona](http://www.percona.com/) a call. Other [MySQL forks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL#Related_projects) are available. I haven't used Percona but they know a lot about tuning InnoDB. Performance improvements over MySQL are moot but read all the answers to this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246/magento-running-on-percona-server-with-xtradb) for some background.

Whatever you do, caching is certainly your friend.

Your product set is large but traffic volume and traffic spikes have a big impact on tuning and hardware choice.

Comment: http://www.percona.com/ is a third party to tune the mysql database?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I have not used its services. I think it also offers an alternative database server called percona server. There is lots of information on its website.

Answer (score 1):

With that many products and categories your shop surely won't perform very fast. But this also depends on your hardware and the amount of Magento StoreViews you will be using.
So the question you should ask is: what is the best caching mechanism to keep your frontend fast?
There are different approaches like using a combination of `Varnish`, `Redis` and `nginx`.

Comment: if i will use these cache. it will reduce the page load time ?